# no mapping found for request - Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-mapping

i'm using spring mvc with java config to make my web app. For some reason spring is rejection all of my beans and it's not finding my servlet mappings.

I'm using tomcat 8.0.23(I updated to the latest to see if that was the issue) and Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE

Error:

```
15:20:26.311 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /users.json
15:20:26.314 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/users.json]
15:20:26.314 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/user-profile-ws/profiles/users.json] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

I think this might be the cause of the error

```
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG 
o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'servletConfig': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'appConfig': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'userController': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'countryPhoneNumberValidator': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'handlerExceptionResolver': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'viewControllerHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.241 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'beanNameHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.242 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'resourceHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcResourceUrlProvider': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcConversionService': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcValidator': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcPathMatcher': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcUrlPathHelper': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcUriComponentsContributor': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'simpleControllerHandlerAdapter': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'mvcViewResolver': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'environment': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemProperties': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'systemEnvironment': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'servletContext': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.243 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'contextParameters': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.244 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'contextAttributes': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.244 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.244 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'messageSource': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.244 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'applicationEventMulticaster': no URL paths identified
15:20:24.244 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'beanNameHandlerMapping'
15:20:24.245 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'resourceHandlerMapping'
15:20:24.245 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'resourceHandlerMapping'
15:20:24.245 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration'
15:20:24.246 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'resourceHandlerMapping' to allow for resolving potential circular references
15:20:24.246 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'resourceHandlerMapping'
15:20:24.246 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcResourceUrlProvider'
15:20:24.246 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'
15:20:24.246 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'
15:20:24.246 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration'
15:20:24.247 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' to allow for resolving potential circular references
15:20:24.247 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'
15:20:24.247 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'
15:20:24.247 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'
15:20:24.247 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration'
15:20:24.258 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcContentNegotiationManager'
15:20:24.258 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mvcConversionService'
15:20:24.258 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mvcValidator'
15:20:24.258 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'mvcValidator'
15:20:24.259 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration'
```

I don't understand why this issue is happening. I think the issue must be in my config, but it looks like its all right

ServletConfig:

```
package software.bytepushers.userprofile.ws.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ContentNegotiationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

/**
 * Created by jaredramirez on 4/18/15.
 */

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("software.bytepushers.userprofile.ws.controllers")
public class ServletConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true).
                ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
                useJaf(false).
                defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                mediaType("xml", MediaType.TEXT_XML).
                mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer:

```
package software.bytepushers.userprofile.ws.config;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

/**
 * Created by jaredramirez on 4/18/15.
 */
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(ServletConfig.class, AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/profiles/*");
    }
}
```

AppConfig:

```
package software.bytepushers.userprofile.ws.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import software.bytepushers.userprofile.models.Country;
import software.bytepushers.userprofile.models.TelephoneNumber;
import software.bytepushers.userprofile.models.validators.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by jaredramirez on 4/29/15.
 */

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("software.bytepushers.userprofile.models")
public class AppConfig {
    static {
        Map<Country, PhoneNumberValidator> phoneNumberValidators = new HashMap<Country, PhoneNumberValidator>();
        phoneNumberValidators.put(Country.UNITED_STATES, new USPhoneNumberValidator());
        phoneNumberValidators.put(Country.UNITED_KINGDOM, new UKPhoneNumberValidator());
        phoneNumberValidators.put(Country.MEXICO, new MexicoPhoneNumberValidator());
        phoneNumberValidators.put(Country.CANADA, new CanadaPhoneNumberValidator());

        CountryPhoneNumberValidator.getInstance().setPhoneNumberValidators(phoneNumberValidators);
    }
}
```

and my Controller

```
package software.bytepushers.userprofile.ws.controllers;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import software.bytepushers.userprofile.models.*;
import software.bytepushers.userprofile.models.exceptions.BaseException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import static software.bytepushers.userprofile.ws.utils.ControllerUtils.*;

/**
 * Created by jaredramirez on 4/18/15.
 */

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/profiles", headers = "Accept=application/json,text/xml")
public class UserController{
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>(); //temporary data storage until database integration

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> getUsers(){
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Person>>(personList, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Person> getIndividualUser(@PathVariable int id){
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(getUser(personList, id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Person> add(@RequestBody Person person) throws BaseException {
        person.validate();
        newUser(personList, person);
        return new ResponseEntity<Person>(person, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

I've looked at all the question related to this that I can find, plus lots of external sites to try to find the problem and I have no idea. Does anyone know what the issue could be caused by?

thanks in advance guys

Comment: Can you show the code of web.xml?

Comment: I'm using java config so I don't have a web.xml @Arpit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. I changed my initializer class to

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ServletConfig.class};
    }
}
```

I am still getting the

> no URL paths identified

issue but it's now functioning